# Getting window position in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a header which is larger when at the top of a page and shrinks a bit when the user scrolls down.  I have accomplished this before without using React by adding an extra CCS element to the .  So I know to use className={*** Not sure what to put here (Some type of check to see if the user is within 0-100px from the top of the page) *** ? "header" : "header  header_shrink"}.

I believe my problem is that since React uses a virtual DOM, the web page always believes that it is scrolled to the maximum height... even when the VDOM is scrolled.  I also believe that react-event-listener is not the answer to my problems.

What are my options here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using:

```
document.body.scrollTop === 0
```

if you only want it at the very top.

alternatively you can do

```
if(window.scrollY==0){
 //user scrolled to the top of the page
}
```

Comment: I tried *className={window.scrollY == 0 ? "header header_shrink" : "header"}* already and it didn't work when I scrolled it off the top. I do believe this behaving in this manner due to the VDOM.